# Printing Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: c++, algorithm

the problem i am facing in the longest subsequence:
For Ex:

```
“ABCDGH” and “AEDFHR” is “ADH” of length 3
```

Code:

```
void lcs( char *X, char *Y, int m, int n )
{
   int L[m+1][n+1];

   /* Following steps build L[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. Note
      that L[i][j] contains length of LCS of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1] */
   for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
   {
     for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
     {
       if (i == 0 || j == 0)
         L[i][j] = 0;
       else if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1])
         L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1;
       else
         L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
     }
   }
```

I don't understand why this line of code:

```
L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
```

What if i want to print the sequence i.e `ADH` how can i do that?

Comment: `int L[m+1][n+1];` VLAs? this doesn't seem C++..

Comment: Hopefully whoever wrote this code also provided documentation. This is really a reverse-engineering question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why this line of code:
>
> ```
> L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
> ```

If the last character of `X[0..i-1]` does not match the last character of `Y[0..j-1]`, then for every common subsequence at least one of these characters does not belong. The answer thus is given by the maximum length for `X[0..i-2]` and `Y[0..j-1]`, or the maximum length for `X[0..i-1]` and `Y[0..j-2]`.

To recover the actual subsequence, we have to trace back these decisions like so.

```
char lcs[min(m, n) + 1];
char *end = lcs;
int i = m;
int j = n;
while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
    if (X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]) {
        *end = X[i - 1];
        end++;
        i--;
        j--;
    } else if (L[i - 1][j] >= L[i][j - 1]) {
        i--;
    } else {
        j--;
    }
}
reverse(lcs, end);
*end = '\0';
puts(lcs);
```

Comment: It should be `while (i >= 0 && j >= 0)`

Comment: @Smac89 If `i >= 0` were the condition, then we would access `X[-1]`.